# clear cache using java code

Tags: java, jmx

I'm trying to write some Java which allows me to clear cache, but is there a problem where I use `CacheManager.getInstance()...` the error is:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
   org/apache/commons/logging/LogFactory
```

When I add commons-logging-1.1.3.jar to the project the error is:

```
net.sf.ehcache.config.ConfigurationFactory parseConfiguration
    WARNING: No configuration found. Configuring ehcache from
    ehcache-failsafe.xml  found in the classpath:
    jar:file:/C:/Users/olawzi/Downloads/ehcache-1.2.3.jar!/ehcache-failsafe.xml
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You solved the first issue correctly, by adding its dependency commons-logging.

The second one is, as stated, a *warning* and not an *error* (but nevertheless, I'd consider it a very serious warning, as the used defaults are quite probably not good for your application).  It means that you forgot to add `ehcache.xml`, ehcache's configuration file, to the classpath.  Add that file and the message will go away.

Also note that the ehcache version you seem to be using (1.2.3) is **very old**, it was released in 2006.  The current version is 2.7, and it can be downloaded [here](http://ehcache.org/downloads/catalog).  Instructions for Maven based projects are also on that page.

Answer (score 0):

you should use maven or gradle to manages jar dependencies: it will bring the good version of all jars: otherwise your problem will be hard to fix